# How to add multiple controls in navigationbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to insert one button and one label in my NavigationBar in iOS.

I have tried with `UISegmentedControl` and it works completely fine with one control!

Now the problem is I want to add multiple controls as i have said before How can I?

Look at my code

```
UIView *v;
[v insertSubview:listingsLabel atIndex:0];
[v insertSubview:shareBtn atIndex:1];

[v setFrame:[self.navigationController.toolbar bounds]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = v;
v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 29);
```

and it gives me error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Answer (score 1):

```
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard "add" button
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray array]];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"All" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Related" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// create a standard "add" button
UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: segmentedControl];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a standard "refresh" button
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

// and put the toolbar in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't init the UIView the right way, it crashes because the iPhone doesn't know what to do with

```
[v insertSubview:listingsLabel atIndex:0];
```

This is because v isn't an object yet. So change

```
UIView *v;
```

to

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 29)];
```

And release it here again (if not using arc)

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = v;
[v release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar on iPhone only supports only a left and right bar button item, and a title view.  Only the (larger) navigation bar on iPad allows an arbitrary number of buttons.

If you're using a navigation bar without a navigation controller, I suppose you could just plop whatever you want onto it as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,60,32)];
    [btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(eventBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 2, 60,25)];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.text =@"  Back";
    [btnBack addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];

    UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
    [btnBack release];
    [backBarBtn release];


    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 170, 40)];
    lblTitle.text = @"ABC";
    lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;
    [lblTitle release];
```